# Kendo Grid Isn't Giving Data For Visible Columns

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was working on a little Angular and JQuery mixed project. And we have a Kendo Grid in action. I was adding the functionality to export kendo grid as an excel file. So, I followed some documentation and got that working just fine.

However, the project is a little weird. let's say we have a data source having 40 columns. But, programmatically we're hiding some columns.
So, I need to be able to export only the visible columns. I tried a few ways to get only visible column, but kendo is giving me all the columns... hidden and visible.

Also, it's not saving the Excel in the column order that's visible on the web page.

These few lines I tried :

```
var _grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
var _grid_ = $("#myGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view().filter(item => !item.hidden);
var __grid__ = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").columns.filter(item => !item.hidden);
```

Unfortunately, `_grid` and `_grid_` are returning data for all the columns, i.e., visible and hidden.
Whereas, as expected `__grid__` is giving just column names.

Where am I wrong? What am I doing wrong?

I need data for just the visible columns... and in the order they appear on the webpage.
Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the hidden columns at the end of the grid and then make them empty as you export.

When you handle the excelExport event in grid options

```
excelExport: this.handleExcelExport
```

and then if you know which columns you want to hide

```
private handleExcelExport(e){
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    let columnsToHide = [5,6]; 
    sheet.rows.forEach(row =>{
       columnsToHide.forEach(column =>{
           row.cells[column] = null;
       })
    })
}
```